# Calculating the intersection points of 3 horizontal lines and a cubic spline

Tags: python, scipy, line, intersection, spline

I have a problem, similar to those, I am posting now. I wanted to calculate the intersection point between one cubic spline and 3 horizontal lines. For all of these horizontal lines I knew the y-value, and I wanted to find out the corresponding x-value of the intersection. 
I hope you can help me. I am sure it is very easy to solve for more experienced coders!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x**2.0)

spline = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = spline(xnew)   


x1=np.arange(0,10)
y1=1/10*np.ones(10)

x2=np.arange(0,10)
y2=2/10*np.ones(10)

x3=np.arange(0,10)
y3=3/10*np.ones(10)


plt.plot(x,y,'o', xnew, ynew, '-', x1,y1, '-.', x2,y2, '-.', x3,y3, '-.')
plt.show()


for i in range(1,4):
    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(spline-y_i))).flatten()
    list_idx.append(idx)


print(list_idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html)'s `roots()` function to find the roots. So first you have to subtract the `y-value` from the function and find the roots, which gives you the `x-value` at that particular `y-value`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x**2.0)

spline = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = spline(xnew)   


x1=np.arange(0,10)
y1=1*np.ones(10)/10

x2=np.arange(0,10)
y2=2*np.ones(10)/10

x3=np.arange(0,10)
y3=3*np.ones(10)/10


plt.plot(x,y,'o', xnew, ynew, '-', x1,y1, '-.', x2,y2, '-.', x3,y3, '-.')
plt.show()


y_val = 0.2
func = np.array(y) - y_val
sub_funct = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, func) # to find the roots we need to substract y_val from the function
root = sub_funct.roots() # find roots here
print(root)
```

This prints the `x` value when `y_val=0.2` as,

```
 [1.36192179]
```

**EDIT**

You can plot the output figure as follows.

```
plt.arrow(root, y_val, 0, -y_val, head_width=0.2, head_length=0.06)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you accept the answer by clicking the tick button just beside my answer? Help a guy earn a badge ;)

Comment: I did! :) And i have an over short question. How about the case, that the function does not have a steady increase of the x-values? Because i read, there are just allowed x-values with an steady increase for using the function interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x,y)? Would be nice if you also have a fast answer for this question! ;)

Comment: According to the documentation, `x-values` must be increasing. I don't think it has to be "steady", or the interpolated plot has to be a really smooth graph to find roots. This should work as long as there's an intersection between the two curves.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Because at work i wanted to calculate the intersection of a horizontal line and a rectangle, that was open on the left side. I always got an error.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

x=[1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
y=[2.5,2.8,2.0,2.8,3.1,3.3,2.1,3.9]

plt.axhline(y=2.6, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.plot(x,y)

y_val = 2.6
func = np.array(y) - y_val
sub_funct = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x,func)
root=sub_funct.roots()
print(root)`